# R : write.dbf() changes my dataframe columns' names

Tags: r, linux, dataframe, dbf

I have a dataframe object made from a loop foreach(..., .combine= rbind). After naming its columns, I save it in a .dbf file thanks to the write.dbf function. But when I open the matching file in LibreOffice Calc my colunms' names have changed and some ",N,19,9", ",N,5,0" or ",N,19,10" (etc) have been appended to them.

I'm working on a Linux Fedora machine and with RStudio.

```
  > c("ID","X","Y",unlist(LU_Named),paste(animalUsed,"_p",sep=""),"Alti_me20","Alti_ra20","Slope_me20","Slope_ra20")

  > print(names(datF_output))

  > write.dbf(datF_output, paste(Base2OutPath,"rANIMALS",sep = "/"), factor2char = FALSE, max_nchar = 254)
```

The print(namesdatF_output)) gives me the correct names :

```
[1] "ID"           "X"            "Y"            "broad_AR"     "conif_AR"    
 [6] "arable_AR"    "imprg_AR"     "rough_AR"     "neutrg_AR"    "calcg_AR"    
[11] "acidg_AR"     "fen_AR"       "heath_AR"     "heathg_AR"    "bog_AR"      
[16] "monta_AR"     "inroc_AR"     "saltwat_AR"   "freshw_AR"    "slitro_AR"   
[21] "slitse_AR"    "litroc_AR"    "litsed_AR"    "saltma_AR"    "urban_AR"    
[26] "suburb_AR"    "Sheep_2003_p" "Alti_me20"    "Alti_ra20"    "Slope_me20"  
[31] "Slope_ra20"
```

but the names in my file are :

```
ID,N,5,0    X,N,19,10   Y,N,19,9    broad_AR,N,19,9 conif_AR,N,19,9 arable_AR,N,19,9    imprg_AR,N,19,9 rough_AR,N,19,10    neutrg_AR,N,19,10   calcg_AR,N,19,9 acidg_AR,N,19,10    fen_AR,N,19,11  heath_AR,N,19,9 heathg_AR,N,19,11   bog_AR,N,19,9   monta_AR,N,19,10    inroc_AR,N,19,9 saltwat_AR,N,19,10  freshw_AR,N,19,9    slitro_AR,N,19,10   slitse_AR,N,19,10   litroc_AR,N,19,15   litsed_AR,N,19,11   saltma_AR,N,19,9    urban_AR,N,19,10    suburb_AR,N,19,11   Sheep_2003,N,19,13  Alti_me20,N,19,13   Alti_ra20,N,19,13   Slope_me20,N,19,14  Slope_ra20,N,19,14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> write.dbf() changes my dataframe columns' names

No, it doesn't; it's just that LibreOffice/OpenOffice handles DBF files in a way where additional information (field type, width and decimals) is appended to the name, cf. [Importing and Exporting dBASE Files](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_dBASE_Files) (*… do not alter or delete the first row in the imported file. This row contains information that is required by a dBASE database*) and [Connecting dBase (xBase)](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Connecting_dBase_(xBase)). Side note: *Excel* doesn't display that information.